# How to convert a "False" string to Boolean value of false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting values as `True` and `False` from back-end. I am trying to convert those values as real Boolean values, But I am getting always `true` with my approach. What would be the correct way to do this?

here is my try:

```
var x = Boolean("False".toLowerCase());

console.log( x ); //giving true instead of false.
```

Comment: Try to send from backend not "False", but correct JSON false (without quotes). It will solve the problem on frontend.

Comment: var x = str.ToLowerCase() == "true";

Comment: try this.. $.parseJSON("False".toLowerCase())

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
var str = "False";
var x = str.toLowerCase() == "false" ? false : true;
```

Comment: if false then false!

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
var x = Boolean("true" == "False".toLowerCase());
```